# Kafka producer: handle connection refused

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to manually handle connection issue with kafka.

When I try this code with kafka unreachable:

```
    public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("topicTest", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)),
                        (metadata, exception) -> {
                            if (exception != null)
                                System.out.println("Exception:" + exception.getMessage());
                        }
                );
            }
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

I fall in an infinity loop:

```
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG NetworkClient:570 - Node -1 disconnected.
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG NetworkClient:680 - Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG NetworkClient:767 - Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG NetworkClient:627 - Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9092.
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG Selector:339 - Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG NetworkClient:590 - Completed connection to node -1.  Fetching API versions.
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG NetworkClient:603 - Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
2017-03-09 16:54:33 DEBUG Selector:375 - Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:169)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:150)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:355)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Even with the callback, I don't have access to the exception.
What is the correct way to handle the connection error?

Comment: Those are DEBUG-level logs which do not necessarily mean something wrong happened. Did you fail to produce messages?

Comment: Yes because Kafka was down.

Comment: The client will buffer your data and retry until Kafka comes back up so there is nothing to do as a producer. As an administrator you should be getting paged if every single broker node in the entire Kafka cluster was down because that is not a common occurrence. It's common that one node might be down but that's why everyone runs 3 or more brokers with a replication factor of 2 or more for each topic partition.